# FluentMigrator sql output - no transactions

Tags: sql-server-2012, fluent-migrator

When using fluentmigrator with the -o switch (output sql to file) I noticed that there is no batch / transactions, I can see the reference to the transactions in the script but they are only comments.

Is there a switch or a way to include transaction control in the sql output?